# TLS WebSocket Server working with firefox client but not with chrome client

Tags: javascript, c++, c++11

I have a `server`, created in `c++` that accepts `TCP` `connections`. We have a few clients that can connect on it (`iOS`, `Android`, `web`). I'm trying to add support for `TLS` now, but I can't seem to get it right. The `TLS` `connection` works when using `Firefox`, but not when using `Chrome`.

The code to start the connection is pretty simple:

```
var socket = new WebSocket(host);
```

The server side is a bit more complex, [it can be found here](http://pastebin.com/5Xr39tyW)

I inspected what happens with `Wireshark`. The results for `Firefox` [can be seen here](http://pastebin.com/AKPhH3Ks) and the results for `Chrome` [can be found here](http://pastebin.com/JkJ59e3F).

What is going wrong here? Does `Chrome` require something special before the `TLS` `connection` can be established?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem. It turns out that there was nothing wrong with my code, but that Google Chrome has a strict poly regarding certificates. I was testing with an untrusted self-signed certificate. When I tested with the company trusted certificate everything worked.